# GROUP BY month and year - SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I got the following SQLite database:

[image]

What I'm trying to do is: sum all values based on `quantidade` grouped by Month/Year (e.g.: 2022/08)

The result I'm expecting grouped by `year/month`:

[image]

My SQL code:

```
SELECT 
        data, SUM(quantidade) AS sum
        
        FROM stock_tracking_Negociacao
        WHERE mercado = 'Futuro'
        GROUP BY strftime('%Y', data), strftime('%m', data)
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `SUBSTR()` here to isolate the month and year, then aggregate:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR(data, 4, 7) AS ym, SUM(quantidade) AS sum
FROM stock_tracking_Negociacao
WHERE mercado = 'Futuro'
GROUP BY 1;
```

Note that SQLite does not have a formal date type, but rather stores dates as strings.

Comment: tks for sharing: I got the point! I just edit to: `SUBSTR(data, 1, 7) as ym`. Unless the date is `dd/mm/YYYY` in my spredsheet (image), inside the database is stored like `YYYY/mm/dd`.

Comment: ...in that case use `SUBSTR(data, 1, 7)` for the year-month.

Answer (score 1):

For SQLite the only valid text-based date format is `YYYY-mm-dd`.
When you use any other format with date functions like `strftime()` the result is `null` and this is the main reason that your code does not work.

Since you mention that in the database the dates have the format `YYYY/mm/dd` you can update to the correct format:

```
UPDATE stock_tracking_Negociacao
SET data = REPLACE(data, '/', '-');
```

and then your query should be:

```
SELECT strftime('%Y-%m', data) AS year_month, 
       SUM(quantidade) AS sum
FROM stock_tracking_Negociacao
WHERE mercado = 'Futuro'
GROUP BY year_month;
```